# Regex - how to get a word after any number of whitespaces and the word struct

Tags: regex

I've been messing around in regex101, trying to find regex code that will return a word after any number of whitespaces and the word `struct`.

So, we could have this:

```
adsf
gjhk
struct


   Test
{
}
```

And the result will be `Test`.

We could also have this:

```
struct Function2{
}
```

And we'd get `Function`.

I tried this: `(?:struct\s+)Test` but per regex101.com, it still picks up both `struct` and the whitespaces.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your actual regex flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
\bstruct\b\s+(\w+)\b
```

Not that it's asking for at least 1 whitespace character after struct (but you could just change it to `\bstruct\b\s*(\w+)\b` if you wanted - not sure that makes much sense)

Comment: Thanks. How would one access the `group 1` match in code, like say, C#?

Comment: @zack_falcon No idea.  `match.Groups[1].Value` probably